# How do I compute the difference between consecutive rows for a histogram?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to create a histogram from some data. SQL Server Developer 2014

Data structure:

```
+-------------Simulations------------+
+ ID | Cycle |  Xa     | nextCycleShort +
+ 0  | 0     |  5.63   | True           +
+ 0  | 1     |  11.45  | False          +
+ 0  | 2     |  12.3   | True           +

+-Parameters-+
+ ID  |  CR  +
+ 0   |  1   +
+ 1   |  2   +
```

In array notation, I want a table with something like:

```
(Xa[i + 1] - Xa[i])*(CASE nextCycleShort[i] WHEN 0 THEN 1.0 ELSE 2.0) AS DIFF
```

From this table, I want to select the `COUNT(CAST(DIFF as int))`. And I want to group that by `CAST(DIFF as INT),Parameters.CR`.

So for each CR, I'll be able to make a histogram of the DIFFs. What does this look like? Here's my attempt at it:

```
SELECT
    p.ControlRange as ControlRange,
    CAST(DIFF as int) as XaMinusXb,
    Count(DIFF) as total_diffs,
    Select q.Xnew FROM
    (SELECT Top 1 Xa AS Xnew
        FROM Simulations t
        WHERE t.ExperimentID = s.ExperimentID AND t.CycleCount > s.CycleCount
        ORDER BY CycleCount DESC) q,
    (q.Xnew - s.Xa)*(CASE WHEN s.nextCycleShort = 0 then 1.0 ELSE 2.0) AS DIFF
FROM Simulations s join Parameters p
GROUP BY CAST(DIFF as int), p.ControlRange
ORDER by p.controlRange ASC, DIFF ASC
        on s.ExperimentID = p.ExperimentID
```

Comment: what sql server version?

Comment: 2014 Developer Edition

Comment: You might also want to check out the SQL Server window functions introduced in SQL Server 2012: http://sqlmag.com/sql-server-2012/how-use-microsoft-sql-server-2012s-window-functions-part-1

Comment: Thanks, that looks really really promising!

Comment: check the `lag` function https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh231256.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Just a thought to do it like this. every row looks back to the previous Xa. You can see how we can get simple diff and also the case based multiplier DIFF:

```
select 
   p.CR, s.Xa,
   lag(s.Xa) over (partition by p.CR order by cycle asc) prev_Xa,
   s.Xa - lag(s.Xa) over (partition by p.CR order by cycle asc) diff,
   case when nextCycleShort = 'False' 
        then 1.0 
        else 2.0 
   end nextCyleShort_int,
  (s.Xa - lag(s.Xa) over (partition by p.CR order by cycle asc)) * (case when nextCycleShort = 'False' then 1.0 else 2.0 end) myDIFF
from 
   (
    select  0  ID, 0   Cycle, 5.63   Xa , 'True'   nextCycleShort union
    select  0  ID,  1   Cycle,  11.45  Xa , 'False'  nextCycleShort union
    select  0  ID,  2    Cycle,  12.3   Xa , 'True'  nextCycleShort 
    ) s
join
  (
   select 0 ID, 1 CR union  
   select 1 ID, 2 CR 
   ) p
on s.ID = p.ID
```